# Python & wxPython - Code Critique - Short Hand / Convenience / Repetition

Tags: python, layout, automation, wxpython, repeat

I'd actually like to start by admitting that I'm terrified to ask this question.  That said, I have the following combination of classes:

A Dialog Class:

```
class formDialog(wx.Dialog):
  def __init__(self, parent, id = -1, panel = None, title = _("Unnamed Dialog"),
               modal = False, sizes = (400, -1)):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, _(title),
                       style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

    if panel is not None:
      self._panel = panel(self)

      self._panel.SetSizeHints(*sizes)

      ds = wx.GridBagSizer(self._panel._gap, self._panel._gap)

      ds.Add(self._panel, (0, 0), (1, 1), wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, self._panel._gap)

      ds.Add(wx.StaticLine(self), (1, 0), (1, 1), wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.LEFT, self._panel._gap)

      self.bs = self.CreateButtonSizer(self._panel._form['Buttons'])

      ds.Add(self.bs, (2, 0), (1, 1), wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL, self._panel._gap)

      ds.AddGrowableCol(0)
      ds.AddGrowableRow(0)

      self.SetSizerAndFit(ds)

      self.Center()

      self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._panel.onOk, id = wx.ID_OK)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._panel.onClose, id = wx.ID_CANCEL)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self._panel.onClose)

      if modal:
        self.ShowModal()
      else:
        self.Show()
```

A Form Class:

```
class Form(wx.Panel):
  reqFields = [
    ('Defaults', {}),
    ('Disabled', [])
  ]

  def __init__(self, parent = None, id = -1, gap = 2, sizes = (-1, -1)):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

    self.SetSizeHints(*sizes)

    self._gap = gap

    self.itemMap = {}

    if hasattr(self, '_form'):
      # There are a number of fields which need to exist in the form
      # dictionary.  Set them to defaults if they don't exist already.
      for k, d in self.reqFields:
        if not self._form.has_key(k):
          self._form[k] = d

      self._build()

  def _build(self):
    """
    The Build Method automates sizer creation and element placement by parsing
    a properly constructed object.
    """

    # The Main Sizer for the Panel.
    panelSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(self._gap, self._gap)

    # Parts is an Ordered Dictionary of regions for the form.
    for group, (key, data) in enumerate(self._form['Parts'].iteritems()):
      flags, sep, display = key.rpartition('-') #@UnusedVariable

      # HR signifies a Horizontal Rule for spacing / layout.  No Data Field.
      if display == 'HR':
        element = wx.StaticLine(self)

        style = wx.EXPAND

      # Any other value contains elements that need to be placed.
      else:
        element = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        # The Row Sizer
        rowSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(self._gap, self._gap)

        for row, field in enumerate(data):
          for col, item in enumerate(field):
            style = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL

            pieces = item.split('-')

            # b for Buttons
            if pieces[0] == 'b':
              control = wx._controls.Button(element, -1, pieces[1])

            # custom items - Retrieve from the _form object
            if pieces[0] == 'custom':
              control = self._form[pieces[1]](element)

              # The row in the Grid needs to resize for Lists.
              panelSizer.AddGrowableRow(group)

              # Now the Row has to grow with the List as well.
              rowSizer.AddGrowableRow(row)

            # custom2 - Same as custom, but does not expand
            if pieces[0] == 'custom2':
              control = self._form[pieces[1]](element)

              style = wx.ALL

            # c for CheckBox
            if pieces[0] == 'c':
              control = wx.CheckBox(element, label = _(pieces[2]), name = pieces[1])

              control.SetValue(int(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], 0)))

            # d for Directory Picker
            if pieces[0] == 'd':
              control = wx.DirPickerCtrl(element, name = pieces[1])

              control.GetTextCtrl().SetEditable(False)

              control.GetTextCtrl().SetName(pieces[1])

              control.GetTextCtrl().SetValue(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], ''))

            # f for File Browser
            if pieces[0] == 'f':
              control = wx.FilePickerCtrl(element, name = pieces[1], wildcard = pieces[2])

              control.GetTextCtrl().SetEditable(False)

              control.GetTextCtrl().SetValue(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], ''))

            # f2 for Save File
            if pieces[0] == 'f2':
              control = wx.FilePickerCtrl(element, name = pieces[1],
                style = wx.FLP_SAVE | wx.FLP_OVERWRITE_PROMPT | wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL,
                wildcard = pieces[2])

              control.GetTextCtrl().SetEditable(False)

            # h for Horizontal Rule - layout helper.
            if pieces[0] == 'h':
              control = wx.StaticLine(element)
              style = wx.EXPAND

            # l for Label (StaticText)
            if pieces[0] == 'l':
              control = wx.StaticText(element, label = _(pieces[1]))

              # Labels do not expand - override default style.
              style = wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL

            # p for Password (TextCtrl with Style)
            if pieces[0] == 'p':
              control = wx.TextCtrl(element, name = pieces[1], style = wx.TE_PASSWORD)

              control.SetValue(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], ''))

            # s for ComboBox (Select)
            if pieces[0] == 's':
              control = wx.ComboBox(element, name = pieces[1],
                choices = self._form['Options'].get(pieces[1], []),
                style = wx.CB_READONLY)

              control.SetValue(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], ''))

            # s2 for Spin Control
            if pieces[0] == 's2':
              control = wx.SpinCtrl(element, name = pieces[1], size = (55, -1),
                min = int(pieces[2]), max = int(pieces[3]))

              control.SetValue(int(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], 1)))

              # Spin Ctrl's do not expand.
              style = wx.ALL

            # t for TextCtrl
            if pieces[0] == 't':
              control = wx.TextCtrl(element, name = pieces[1])

              try:
                control.SetValidator(self._form['Validators'][pieces[1]])
              except KeyError: pass # No Validator Specified.

              control.SetValue(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], ''))

            # tr for Readonly TextCtrl
            if pieces[0] == 'tr':
              control = wx.TextCtrl(element, name = pieces[1], style = wx.TE_READONLY)

              control.SetValue(self._form['Defaults'].get(pieces[1], ''))

            # Check for elements disabled by default.  Store reference to 
            # Element in itemMap for reference by other objects later.
            if len(pieces) > 1:
              if pieces[1] in self._form['Disabled']:
                control.Enable(False)

              self.itemMap[pieces[1]] = control

            # Place the control in the row.
            rowSizer.Add(control, (row, col), (1, 1), style, self._gap)

            if style == wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL:
              rowSizer.AddGrowableCol(col)

        if 'NC' not in flags:
          sb = wx.StaticBox(element, -1, _(display))
          sz = wx.StaticBoxSizer(sb, wx.VERTICAL)

          sz.Add(rowSizer, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)

          element.SetSizerAndFit(sz)
        else:
          element.SetSizerAndFit(rowSizer)

      panelSizer.Add(element, (group, 0), (1, 1), wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, self._gap)

    panelSizer.AddGrowableCol(0)

    self.SetSizerAndFit(panelSizer)

  def getDescendants(self, elem, list):
    children = elem.GetChildren()

    list.extend(children)

    for child in children:
      self.getDescendants(child, list)

  def getFields(self):
    fields = []

    self.getDescendants(self, fields)

    # This removes children we can't retrieve values from.  This should result
    # in a list that only contains form fields, removing all container elements.
    fields = filter(lambda x: hasattr(x, 'GetValue'), fields)

    return fields

  def onOk(self, evt):
    self.onClose(evt)

  def onClose(self, evt):
    self.GetParent().Destroy()
```

The Form is meant to be used by subclassing like so:

```
class createQueue(Form):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self._form = {
      'Parts' : OrderedDict([
        ('Queue Name', [
          ('t-Queue Name',)
        ])
      ]),
      'Buttons' : wx.OK | wx.CANCEL
    }

    Form.__init__(self, parent)

class generalSettings(Form):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self._form = {
      'Parts': OrderedDict([
        ('Log Settings', [
          ('l-Remove log messages older than: ', 's2-interval-1-10', 's-unit')
        ]),
        ('Folder Settings', [
          ('l-Spool Folder Location:', 'd-dir'),
          ('l-Temp Folder Location:', 'd-temp')
        ]),
        ('Email Notifications', [
          ('l-Alert Email To:', 't-alert_to'),
          ('l-Alert Email From:', 't-alert_from'),
          ('l-Status Email From:', 't-status_from'),
          ('l-Alert Email Server:', 't-alert_host'),
          ('l-Login:', 't-alert_login'),
          ('l-Password:', 'p-alert_password')
        ]),
        ('Admin User', [
          ('c-req_admin-Require Admin Rights to make changes.',)
        ]),
        ('Miscellaneous', [
          ('l-Print Worker Tasks:', 's2-printtasks-1-256', 'l-Job Drag Options:', 's-jobdrop')
        ])
      ]),
      'Options': {
        'unit': ['Hours', 'Days', 'Months'],
        'jobdrop': ['Move Job to Queue', 'Copy Job to Queue']
      },
      'Buttons': wx.OK | wx.CANCEL
    }

    Form.__init__(self, parent)
```

These might be used like so:

```
formDialog(parent, panel = createQueue, title = 'Create a Queue', sizes = (200, -1))

formDialog(parent, panel = generalSettings, title = "General Settings")
```

Whew, that's a ton, and thanks to anyone who makes it down this far.  The idea is that I want something that takes care of the monotonous parts of layout in wxPython.  I am designing a user interface that will need to create 100's of different Dialogs and Forms.  I wanted something that would allow me to generate the forms dynamically from a structured object.

I'd like to hear other developers' thoughts on this kind of approach.  The closest I've seen to something similar is Drupal's Form API.  I feel like it is viable for these reasons:

- Easily rearrange fields.
- No need to create / manage Sizers manually.
- Compound / complex forms can be created easily.
- Display helper elements (StaticBoxSizers, Static Lines) are easily added.

I am concerned that it is an undesirable approach for these reasons:

- Long `_build()` function body in the Form Class.
- May not be clear to other developers at first glance.
- Uses Structured Strings to define fields.
- There may be a better way.

Any thoughts, constructive, destructive, or otherwise will all be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also try wxFormDesigner or XRCed.

Comment: I dislike XML, but found some things in the suggested projects that I can use to clean up my classes above.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll probably end up with something that resembles what I have above, but that's cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using wx, you should study wxglade. It's a graphical GUI builder which you use to build your GUI and it generates a `.wxg` file with the layout, and you can load that into your script.

The file is actually just xml, so you can programatically generate it and dynamically load different GUIs from it. Maybe that helps.

Comment: I looked at wxglade a bit, but found it's generated code to be overly verbose.  I wasn't aware that the .wxg file was xml though, so maybe I'll need to revisit it.  Thanks!